# A Variation on Backward Mathematical Induction

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, logic, proof-writing, induction

I came across this [page](http://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Resource/AL/Different%20kinds%20of%20Mathematical%20Induction.pdf) on various kinds of Mathematical Inductions

Can someone please give me an intuitive understanding to as why the following Backward or Reverse Induction should work?

> IF
>
> (1) $\ \ \ P(1)$ holds;
>
> (2)$\ \ \ P(2^k)$ for some $k \in \mathbb N$ $\Rightarrow  P(2^{k+1})$ holds
>
> (3)$\ \ \ P(k)$ for some $k \in \mathbb N$ $\Rightarrow  P(k-1)$ holds
>
> THEN
>
> $P(n)$ holds for all $n \in \mathbb N$

Is it because $P(2^k) \Rightarrow P(2^{k+1})$ allows us for any number $m \le 2^k$ to be reached by first applying (2) and then working backwards using (3)? If so couldn't we use powers of 3 provided we also prove $P(2)$ holds in (1)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you looking at (8)?

Comment: @Sentinel135 Yes

Comment: then I'm going to edit your post to reflect it. you have some things a bit off.

Comment: @Sentinel135 Sure. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. My answer would have been extremely similar to Artimis Fowl's, so I shall not post an answer. but let us know if that didn't answer your question on reverse strong induction.

Comment: For other techniques closely related to induction take a look at transfinite induction and infinite descent.

Comment: (2) and (3) should not say for some k  but should say for all k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is correct, and powers of $3$ would certainly work. In general, if $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is some function satisfying $f(x) > x$ for all $x$, then we can use $$(2): P(f^{(k)}(1)) \text{ for some }k \in \mathbb{N} \implies P(f^{(k+1)}(x)) \text{ holds}$$ (where $f^{(m)}$ denotes applying $f$ $m$ times) If we wanted to show $P(m)$, we can apply $f$ $m$ times to $1$ to get $P(k)$ for some value $k\geq m$, then use $(3)$ repeatedly to show $P(m)$.

Answer (score 1):

Condition (2) should be re-written as $$\forall k\in \{0\}\cup \mathbb N\; (P(2^k)\implies P(2^{k+1})).$$ And Condition (3) should be re-written as $$\forall k \in \mathbb N \backslash \{1\}\;(P(k)\implies P(k-1)).$$

(i). Then by (1) and (2) and ordinary induction on $k\geq 0$ we have $\forall k\in \{0\}\cup \mathbb N\;(P(2^k)). $

(ii).Suppose there exists $k_0\in \mathbb N$ such that $\neg P(k_0).$ Observe that (3) is equivalent to $$\forall k\in \mathbb N\;([\neg P(k)]\implies \neg P(k+1)). $$ So if $\neg P(k_0)$ then by  ordinary induction on $k\geq k_0$ we have $\forall k\in \mathbb N\;(k\geq k_0\implies \neg P(k)).$

This implies that if $n\in \mathbb N$ and $2^n>k_0$ then $\neg P(2^n).$  But there does exist $n\in \mathbb N$ with $2^n>k_0,$ and according to (i) we have $P(2^n).$ Contradiction. So supposing  there exists $k\in \mathbb N$ with $\neg P(k_0)$  is paradoxical.

Intuitively: To get $P(k)$ we take $n$ with $2^n>k.$ By (1),(2), and (i) we get $P(2^n).$ Then we use (3) to "count down" from $2^n$ to $k.$